# Ruby: Selenium and WebMock causing TypeError

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, webmock

The combination of WebMock and Selenium is causing a Type Error on the first call to `visit`

```
 Failure/Error: id['ELEMENT'] || id['element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf']
      TypeError:
        no implicit conversion of String into Integer
# /selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/bridge_helper.rb:43:in `[]'
# /selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/bridge_helper.rb:43:in `element_id_from'
# /selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `block in find_elements_by'
# /selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `each'
# /selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `map'
# /selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `find_elements_by'
# /selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:79:in `find_elements'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:86:in `find_xpath'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:108:in `find_xpath'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/queries/selector_query.rb:135:in `block in resolve_for'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/queries/selector_query.rb:131:in `resolve_for'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:40:in `block in find'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:38:in `find'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:92:in `fill_in'
# /capybara-2.14.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:784:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
# /capybara-angular-0.2.5/lib/capybara/angular/dsl.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
# ./spec/features/assesment_picker_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

However, when I remove all of the WebMock code my tests execute.  I've allowed `localhost` in my WebMock exceptions, however my tests still fail to execute.  I'm not sure what else I need to do to allow Selenium to run while using WebMock.  Additionally, if the Selenium specs are the first to run, they pass.

#### Capybara Setup

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.app_host = root_url #retrieved elsewhere

  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

  config.save_path = File.join Dir.pwd, 'tmp', 'capybara'
end

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.default_driver
Capybara.javascript_driver = Capybara.default_driver
```

#### Spec Helper

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'webmock/rspec'

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true, allow: [/browserstack.com/])

# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

#### Hash returned from find_elements in remote/bridge#find_elements_by

```
$ how
"css selector"
$ what
"a"
$ execute :find_elements, {}, {using: how, value: what}

{
              "acceptSslCerts" => true,
     "applicationCacheEnabled" => false,
    "browserConnectionEnabled" => false,
                 "browserName" => "chrome",
                      "chrome" => {
        "chromedriverVersion" => "2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b)",
                "userDataDir" => "/var/folders/2h/ws89fb2s381c9_3fzy6f9gzm0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.RPWXqC"
    },
         "cssSelectorsEnabled" => true,
             "databaseEnabled" => false,
               "handlesAlerts" => true,
              "hasTouchScreen" => false,
           "javascriptEnabled" => true,
      "locationContextEnabled" => true,
      "mobileEmulationEnabled" => false,
                "nativeEvents" => true,
    "networkConnectionEnabled" => false,
            "pageLoadStrategy" => "normal",
                    "platform" => "Mac OS X",
                   "rotatable" => false,
           "takesHeapSnapshot" => true,
             "takesScreenshot" => true,
    "unexpectedAlertBehaviour" => "",
                     "version" => "57.0.2987.133",
           "webStorageEnabled" => true
}
```

#### Tools

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b)
$ bundle list selenium-webdriver
/Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0
```

Comment: Post the stack trace of the error message so we can see where it's actually coming from.  Additionally, I hope you realize WebMock won't actually let you mock the responses to requests from the browser, it only allows for mocking requests your app makes, and generally is frowned upon using with feature specs (capybara) which should be end to end.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the selenium-webdriver you're using isn't compatible with the version of chromedriver you're using.  Update to the latest selenium-webdriver (3.4.0 as I'm typing this), and chromedriver (2.29).  You may also need to instruct WebMock to allow connections on 127.0.0.1 for the communications between selenium and chromedriver, depending on exactly how you have it configured.

Comment: @TIMBERings did you just update to that, because your error log very clearly shows selenium-webdriver 3.2.2 ?

Comment: I didn't update the stack trace.  Now everything should be updated.  I included some more information from further debugging

Comment: @TIMBERings The response you show is not a valid response to the :find_elements call so I'm confused as to why you're getting that.  You don't have WebMock playing back pre-recorded responses using VCR, etc do you?  If so you need to turn that off for the selenium communication.

Comment: That's what I don't understand either.  The actual application under test has WebMock enabled to mock information from our API.    include WebMock::API;  WebMock.enable!, WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true).  Other than that, no use of VCR or anything similar.

Comment: @TIMBERings It really sounds like you're somehow mocking the selenium connections.  I guess search your project for some of the strings in the invalid response you're seeing.  Other than that it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was importing the curb module for Browserstack and SauceLabs always, not just if I was running a remote driver.